# Instead of turning into buttons, my row just dissapears

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next problem: Whenever the input fields are checked and correctly filled out they should turn into green buttons, however whenever the check happens and they should change into green buttons they just dissapear. I `console.log()` the green buttons and that returns "undefined" to me. Look at the picture and then the first 3 input fields:

[image: look at the first 3 input fields of the first row]

now take a look at the second one AFTER the check:
[image: See the first 3 inputs of the first row now]

as you can see they dissapear. I did inspect element and I can't find them.

How my code looks like:

```
$.map(exercise.syllables, function (syllable, j) { 
        if (!syllable || !syllable.trim().length) {
       // If it doesn't exist or is an empty string, return early without creating/appending elements
           return;
      }

        var innerSylCol = $('<div/>', {
            class: 'col-md-3 inputSyllables'
        });

        var sylInput = $('<input/>', {
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control syl-input',
            'name':  +c++,
            'id': +idsyll++
        }).on('blur', function() {
            var cValue = $(this).val();

            if(cValue === "") {
               return;
            }

            if (cValue === syllable) {
                correctSylls.push(cValue);
                console.log(correctSylls);
            }

            if (exercise.syllables.length === correctSylls.length) {
                $(this).closest('.syll-row').find('input.syl-input').replaceWith(getCorrectBtn(cValue));
              //  console.log(getCorrectBtn(cValue));
                S.addRight();
                S.playRight();
          } else if (cValue !== syllable){
                $(this).css({'color':'#e00413'});
                S.playWrong();
                S.addWrong();
             }
          });
```

the function where I create the button:

```
function getCorrectBtn(value) {
var correctBtn = $('<button/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-success buttonCorrect',
    'type': 'button',
    'id': "button" + CBC++,
    'value': value
});
}
```

And the all the CSS that could be related to my input fields:

```
input[type="text"] {
font-size: 150%;
margin-top: 1vh;
transition: color 1s;
}

.btn {
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
height: 38px;
margin: 5px;
outline: none !important;
}


input {
width:100%;
padding:5px;
outline: none !important;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You have no `return` in `getCorrectBtn`.

Comment: Show your html code as well.

Comment: You were correct @jaboja, but it doesn't show the value given to the input fields. it only creates a button now. (We came a step closer to the solution so thank you very much). Shah, my HTML is only the minimum. Everything else (such as input fields etc.) are made from the code above.

Comment: It would be easier if you have posted the code as a runnable snippet.